# emacs: command not found problem

Tags: raspbian, speech-recognition

I'm trying to install speech recognition using sphinx engine.
I need to let the system know where my files are. To do this, you tried to edit the /etc/ld.so.conf path as the root by typing sudo emacs /etc/ld.so.conf.

but it shows me ''emacs: command not found'' 
what is the problem and how I can solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: You don't have emacs installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor **emacs** isn't installed by default on Raspbian. Before using it you have to install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install emacs
```